# Scala: flatMap with tuples

Tags: scala, flatmap

Why is the below statement valid for `.map()` but not for `.flatMap()`?

```
 val tupled = input.map(x => (x*2, x*3))

 //Compilation error: cannot resolve reference flatMap with such signature
 val tupled = input.flatMap(x => (x*2, x*3))
```

This statement has no problem, though:

```
val tupled = input.flatMap(x => List(x*2, x*3))
```

Comment: What is type of `input`? Check `map` and `flatMap` method signatures. Its have different parameters that's why your code has compile error.

Comment: Because `flatMap` is used for flattening structure. When you get a `M[M[A]]` with `map` you will get `M[A]` with `flatMap`.

Comment: The nested `M` can sometimes be different, `N`.. For example `List[Option[String]]` => `List[String]`

Comment: the thing is `a.flatMap(a => b)` can be roughly approximated by  `a.map(a => b).flatten`. Basically for `flatMap` to work, the return type of function should be a monad or something which you can flatten.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `input` if of type `List[Int]`, `map` takes a function from `Int` to `A`, whereas `flatMap` takes a function from `Int` to `List[A]`.

Depending on your use case you can choose either one or the other, but they're definitely not interchangeable.

For instance, if you are merely transforming the elements of a `List` you typically want to use `map`:

```
List(1, 2, 3).map(x => x * 2) // List(2, 4, 6)
```

but you want to change the structure of the `List` and - for example - "explode" each element into another list then flattening them, `flatMap` is your friend:

```
List(1, 2, 3).flatMap(x => List.fill(x)(x)) // List(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3)
```

Using `map` you would have had `List(List(1), List(2, 2), List(3, 3, 3))` instead.

Answer (score 4):

To understand how this is working, it can be useful to explicitly unpack the functions you're sending to `map` and `flatMap` and examine their signatures. I've rewritten them here, so you can see that `f` is a function mapping from `Int` to an `(Int, Int)` tuple, and `g` is a function that maps from `Int` to a `List[Int]`.

```
val f: (Int) => (Int, Int) = x => (x*2, x*3)
val g: (Int) => List[Int] = x => List(x*2, x*3)

List(1,2,3).map(f)
//res0: List[(Int, Int)] = List((2,3), (4,6), (6,9))
List(1,2,3).map(g)
//res1: List[List[Int]] = List(List(2, 3), List(4, 6), List(6, 9))
//List(1,2,3).flatMap(f)  // This won't compile
List(1,2,3).flatMap(g)
//res2: List[Int] = List(2, 3, 4, 6, 6, 9)
```

So why won't `flatMap(f)` compile? Let's look at the signature for `flatMap`, in this case pulled from the `List` implementation:

```
final override def flatMap[B, That](f : scala.Function1[A, scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[B]])(...)
```

This is a little difficult to unpack, and I've elided some of it, but the key is the `GenTraversableOnce` type. `List`, if you follow it's chain of inheritance up, has this as a trait it is built with, and thus a function that maps from some type `A` to a `List` (or any object with the `GenTraversableOnce` trait) will be a valid function. Notably, tuples do not have this trait.

That is the in-the-weeds explanation why the typing is wrong, and is worth explaining because any error that says 'cannot resolve reference  with such a signature' means that it can't find a function that takes the explicit type you're offering. Types are very often inferred in Scala, and so you're well-served to make sure that the type you're giving is the type expected by the method you're calling.

Note that `flatMap` has a standard meaning in functional programming, which is, roughly speaking, any mapping function that consumes a single element and produces n elements, but your final result is the concatenation of all of those lists. Therefore, the function you pass to `flatMap` will always expect to produce a list, and no `flatMap` function would be expected to know how to act on single elements.